# File reader execute multiple times in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load images in to page for preview before uploading with javascript.

I have following code:

```
holder.onclick = function(event) {

    function chooseFile(name) {
        var chooser = $(name);
        chooser.unbind('change');
        chooser.change(function(evt) {

            function loadFile(file, callback) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                (reader.onload = function(file) {

                    console.log(f);    
                    var output = document.createElement('input');
                    output.type = 'image';
                    output.classList.add('image-responsive');
                    output.classList.add('col-xs-12');
                    output.name = f;
                    output.id = f;
                    output.src = reader.result;

                    var x = document.getElementById('OrigName');
                    x.appendChild(output);

                    return callback(output);
                })(f = file.name);

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
                console.log(i);
                var file = evt.target.files[i];
                loadFile(file, function(output) {
                   // console.log(output);
                });
            }
        });
        chooser.trigger('click');
    }
    chooseFile('#fileDialog');
}
```

Problem is, whenever i load image, code inside reader.onload method execute twice, and in console i 2x result of console.log(f) and 2 errors that 'localhost/null is not found'.

When i remove (f=file.name), script execute as it should be, but then i don't have file.name variable inside reader scope.

EDIT:

Here's JSFiddle of my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/onedevteam/udmz34z0/6/

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is, whenever i load image, code inside reader.onload method execute twice

This is because in your code you have this.

```
(reader.onload = function(file) {
           //...
           //...
})(f = file.name);  // <---- self executing function.

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Here you are using "**Self Executing function**" for the `reader.onload`, So what happens is it will execute once when it hits this line of code, And again when `reader.readAsDataURL(file)`  has completed reading. So `remove the "self executing function " and you logic will run only once`

> When i remove (f=file.name), script execute as it should be, but then i don't have file.name variable inside reader scope.

to get the file name just add it in a variable and use it like this.

```
var fileName = file.name;
reader.onload = function() {
           //...
           //...
           output.name = fileName ;
           output.id = fileName ;
  }; // <-- self executing function REMOVED
```

---

Also I feel there is no need to save the file name into a variable because the variable `file` passed into function is sufficient to get the job done. So below would be the final code as per my suggestion.

```
          function loadFile(file, callback) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function() {

                console.log(file.name); //
                var output = document.createElement('input');
                output.type = 'image';
                output.classList.add('image-responsive');
                output.classList.add('col-xs-12');
                output.name = file.name; //
                output.id = file.name;   //
                output.src = reader.result;

                var x = document.getElementById('OrigName');
                x.appendChild(output);

                return callback(output);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `reader.onload` at least twice.  You have this function inside another function `loadFile()`, and you call it immediately (which is why you only see this behavior when you have `(f=file.name)` there), but then also inside the `chooser.change` function you have that for-loop that calls `loadFile()`.  Perhaps ou could set the `file.name` variable somewhere other than `(f=file.name)` and then make `reader.onload` not execute automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your code structured, your onload handler will be executed twice, once when you define it, and then again when the "load" event fires. When you wrap a function definition inside parens:

```
(reader.onload = function (file) { ... })(f = filename)
```

you're saying "define this function and execute it immediately."

What you really want is a function that returns a function, like this:

```
function makeOnLoadHandler (filename) {
    return function (file) {
        // ... do whatever you need to with file and filename
    };
}

reader.onload = makeOnLoadHandler(someFileName);
```

The outer function, `makeOnLoadHandler()`, creates a closure around your `filename` variable, and when the inner function handles the reader's `load` event, it will see the `filename` that you passed in when you called makeOnLoadHandler.