# Angular: FileReader - reader executes too many times

Tags: javascript, angular, filereader

I have this FileReader with which I am able to read folders:

```
private fileCache: any[];
  private folderReader$: Subject<any[]> = new Subject();

  public readFolder(files: any[]) {
    this.fileCache = [];
    this.readFile(0, files);
    return this.folderReader$.asObservable();
  }

  private readFile(index, files) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if (index >= files.length) {
      this.folderReader$.next(this.fileCache);
      return;
    }
    const file = files[index];
    const filename = file.name;
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.fileCache.push({
        name: filename,
        content: e.target.result});
      this.readFile(index+ 1, files);
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

Now the strange thing is, whenever I choose the second input, it runs multiple times. If i choose just one input, everything is fine...

When for example using this:

```
this.folderReader.readFolder(data.target.files).subscribe(files => {
    console.log(test);
}
```

after just two inputs, the console will display test three times:

```
test
test
test
```

Like i saw here: [File reader execute multiple times in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474865/file-reader-execute-multiple-times-in-javascript) it's probably a matter with the onload running multiple times so what i tried was removing this line:

```
  this.readFile(index+ 1, files);
```

so that the whole function won't be started all over again...
However, after that, it didn't work at all, as it probably needs the `index+1` so it can go trough all the files i reckon.

What am I doing wrong here? Why does the FileReader execute itself multiple times instead of just one time per input?

Comment: Whats the difference between "one and two inputs"? You call the function twice? Please provide a minimal [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) with your code to reproduce your question. Its quite easier to debug.

Comment: I've made this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hv8d2s to reproduce the error:  if you choose a folder one time, it will display all the filenames in the console. If you choose an additional folder, it will display the names of the first folder two times instead of one and if you choose two additional folders it will display the filenames of the third folder three times instead of one and i cant figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the way you handle the Subject.

One workaround is to reinit your Subject in the readFolder call, e.g.:

```
  public readFolder(files: any[]) {
    this.folderReader$ = new Subject();
    this.fileCache = [];
    this.readFile(0, files);
    return this.folderReader$.asObservable();
  }
```

But the better way is to use another Subject like the BehaviorSubject from rxjs.

Have a look at [Understanding rxjs BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject and AsyncSubject](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)